# How to plot with matplotlib directed graphs obtained from QgsGraphBuilder?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Developing a plugin for QGIS, I have a shapefile with graph vertices and graph edges and I would like to plot a selection of them, with matplotlib, as a directed graph. How can I do that?

For now, I have something like this:

```
from qgis.networkanalysis import *

vl = self.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
director = QgsLineVectorLayerDirector(vl, -1, '', '', '', 3)
properter = QgsDistanceArcProperter()
director.addProperter(properter)
crs = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().destinationCrs()
builder = QgsGraphBuilder(crs)
graph = builder.graph()
```